# Как поменять расположение блоков с помощью Bootstrap 4?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью bootstrap 4 [image: поменять порядок и базовые линии блоков]

Пробовал менять порядок элементов, но тогда последний блок получается просто на новой  линии

Comment: Вставляете копию картинки между заголовком и описанием, делаете ее невидимой на декстопе (display: none), а картинку которая слева делаете невидимой на мобилке. Костыль, но другого выхода не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже к такому выводу пришел.... Думал на бутстрапе есть что-то поэлегантней

Comment: Вообще-то есть, но, признаюсь честно, я никогда этим не пользовался. Можете тут почитать: https://itchief.ru/bootstrap/grid-column-ordering-v3